# Blank ID when saving new items on SobiPro

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I'm not sure how to describe this.  I am moving to a new host for various reasons and in the process of moving to a new host, I put my site back together and imported the database.  Everything looked good except for when I try to put in a new entry into SobiPro (What I use to manage my listing).

What happens is this:

- When clicking to add a new Category or Entry the ID comes up as 0.
- On the front end, there is a 'blank' spot where the new category or entry should be.
- When I try to delete it from the back end I get the error "Please select at least one item to perform this action" (I did make sure that I had it selected).
- In the back end even, there is a blank spot where the new entry should be (much like the front end).
- I am also using a module that is used to display all the artists in the listing, but when you start clicking links, names will duplicate in the list and creating redundant links (I have since disabled this because after you click enough times to navigate, the site crashes completely).

Images for Reference: [Database Entry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IKm5.png) - [Back End](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gyn7.png) - [Front End](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SN5ax.png) - [Duplicate Links](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyGaP.png)

- Current Link (What is should look like): http://eve-sounds.com
- New Link (The Rebuilt Site w/ Issues): http://djyumene.com/evesounds/

I wish I could give more details but I don't know what to look for.  I've never come across this before.  I know Joomla but I'm not very knowledgeable about how to fix database issues. I tried to turn on error reporting and debugging but I am getting literally no errors to go off of so all I can do is describe what's going on.

Comment: How do you move your data ? It is the same configuration PHP, MySQL... on the 2 providers ? If it works, maybe you lost data on transfer... bad mysql export/import  or files corrupt on ftp. Check .htaccess, I see your new site is not in the base directory /evesounds

Comment: The joomla is a fresh install and everything is the same from the old site. I don't see how I lost any data.  When I import, everything is there, it's when I try to add a new entry to the new site is when I am presented with these errors.

Comment: Unable debug mode and check what happen.

Comment: Enabling debug mode results in a white screen.  No errors display in that mode.